# C#: How can I programmatically loop through all controls on a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, controls

I'm in the process of creating a front-end Windows Forms application, which will have multiple uses.  One of those uses will be to allow the end-user to manage the contents of a database table.

At the moment, my form contains a DataGridView object which uses a DataTable as its source.  That datatable is populated from a stored procedure which selects every row from the table based on criteria specified by the end user.  I want to put code into the DataGridView which will look at the row that's been selected by the user, and will populate a series of text boxes with the details from that row.

I want to avoid hard-coding a text box for each column in the DataGridView, since it's highly possible that in the future I might add columns to the underlying stored procedure.  Therefore, my plan is that the first time the user selects a row, the application would dynamically create a text box for each column, size that text box appropriately (both height and width) and add the appropriate labels.

So far, the code I've written creates a brand-new DataTable, and adds columns to store the following information about each column in the DataGridView:

1. The actual name of the DataGridView column;
2. The name that I wish to give to the associated label;
3. The text that I wish to assign to the associated label;
4. The top and left positions of the associated label;
5. The name that I wish to give to the associated text box;
6. The value that I wish to display in the associated text box;

So far when the user initially clicks on a row, everything is working well: the text boxes get created in a vertical column, with the associated label to the left of each text box and the appropriate value displayed in each one.  Each text box has its width dynamically set based on the contents of that text box so that everything can easily be seen.

The difficulty comes when the user changes from one row of the DataGridView to another.  The code that runs to create each control looks like this:

```
            if (pnlManageJobManagerOutcomes.Controls.Contains(txtCurrent))
            {

                pnlManageJobManagerOutcomes.Controls.Remove(txtCurrent);

            }
            if (!pnlManageJobManagerOutcomes.Controls.Contains(txtCurrent))
            {

                pnlManageJobManagerOutcomes.Controls.Add(txtCurrent);

            }
```

When the code first runs, all seems to be fine.  However, if it gets fired a second time (at which point it should remove and re-create the control) it doesn't seem to detect the prior existence of the control and simply creates a second copy of it in the form.

For information, the form I'm building has multiple uses which are dictated by a series of buttons.  Therefore, I'm creating the controls for this particular use inside a Panel (pnlManageJobManagerOutcomes).  I'm completely stumped as to why the code doesn't spot the existence of those controls during subsequent executions.

TIA

Comment: "at which point it should remove and re-create the control" where is the necessity to do that? don't you want just to input the newly selected row information into the textboxes? furthermore: what is `txtCurrent` ? you are checking a collection of controls for the existence of the instance of this object, you are not comparing values in that call!

Comment: The issue remains the same though: I would only want the control to be created if it doesn't already exist.  txtCurrent is a variable which has been populated by a ForEach loop run against the datatable that was populated from the structure of the DataGridView source.

Comment: What is the point of checking whether a Control exists, when this Control has been created at the same time the source of data is created (as you're saying)? You'd have no rows to move to in a DataGridView if it had no DataSource set. If it can select a Row, then you already have those Controls -- You should dispose of the Controls already created in case the source of data changes, then create a new bunch, according to the new data -- If you have other issues, show how you create these Controls in the first place and how their references are stored (you're using a Field name, which is weird)

Comment: It seems that some code necessary for understanding your problem is missing: Where and how do you get txtCurrent? Where do you (re-)create the control?

Comment: No need to keep creating controls like that. Just use the designer to layout the controls and use a `BindingSource` bound to the `DataTable` and bind the data sources/properties to the corresponding fields/table. Unless you have to, i.e. different set of controls based on given conditions.

Comment: Jimi, that makes a lot of sense.  I could create the controls at the point the DataGridView source gets bound to the underlying DataTable.

Comment: dr.null, I want the code to be completely dynamic, rather than adding the controls in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to do it, which may seem to be clunky but which seems to work.

Since it doesn't appear that I can check to see whether the Panel I'm working with Contains the field name, I've written a method which will loop through the controls in that Panel and return a count of the number of instances of that control in the Panel's Controls array.  If the method returns a 0, this means the Control doesn't exist in that Panel and I can go ahead and create it.

Comment: "Since it doesn't appear that I can check to see whether the Panel I'm working with Contains the field name" you can check that, you just did not do it. Your code checks for the existence of an instance and not of a string.

Comment: I did check it. I did a foreach loop on all of the objects in the panel, and checked each object.name against the name of the object I wanted to check for, and it didn’t find it. Weirdly, the code allowed me to have multiple objects with identical names.

Comment: I am talking about your posted code. We can only see as much as you show us. All the rest that you did we don't know and don't see. this is why I wrote "Your code checks for...". But I am happy to hear that you solved your problem. But then again you write: "I did check it. " and at the same time "t doesn't appear that I can check " which one is it?